# Where does Google Chrome put .desktop files?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, unity-dash

I wanted to use Whatsapp Web but since there's no PWA app or a native app written for Ubuntu... I had a really good idea, it's like electron apps.
Just use Chrome for a shortcut, so I did.

The problem is that the icon is really annoying, and I wanted to change it, so the Unity Dash will be as fine as I want.

[image: Chrome "Add to desktop..." feature]

Translated: Chrome menu -> **More tools** -> **Add to desktop...**

The thing is... I searched a lot and I can't tell where chrome puts that .desktop files.. because Unity Dash recognizes it! 
So I looked for it in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` and it's not there!

I just want to edit that .desktop file, please help.

Comment: Did you look in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: yep, it's not there too!

Comment: What are the contents of `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: @pomsky only 1 file and its called `mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome creates two .desktop files, one on the desktop (in `~/Desktop`) and another in `~/.local/share/applications`. The latter is shown in the Dash. To find it, run

```
grep -ri "whatsapp" ~/.local/share/applications
```

E.g. mine was called `chrome-hnpfjngllnobngcgfapefoaidbinmjnm-Default.desktop`. I was able to edit the `Icon` field and have it take effect in the Dash.

Comment: pomsky was right, for some weird reason I wasn't able to see that .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications` until I rebooted.

Comment: I found the file there, but it was weird, the `Name` was `Name=Socket.io tester`. I expected something like `Name=Google Chrome`

Comment: @Anand The `Name` is the name of the app. For example I have `Google Keep - notes and lists` and `TeamViewer`.